# WordPress hook after post content and meta update

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

I want to update one of my meta field and redirect and I am using `post_updated`hook. Here is my code.

```
function job_publish_status( $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before ) {
   $job_published_date = get_the_time("Y-m-d", $post_ID);
   $expire_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($job_published_date. ' + 60 days'));
   update_post_meta($post_ID, '_job_expires', $expire_date);
   $url = get_site_url();
   $url = $url.'/wp-admin/post.php?post='.$post_ID.'&action=edit';
   wp_redirect( $url );
   exit; 
}
add_action('post_updated', 'job_publish_status', 99, 3 );
```

It is updating this `_job_expires` meta field and redirecting correctly. When I edit post content and title, its updates title and content but it is not updating other meta fields in this post. 
Is there any hook which triggers after post content update and meta fields update ?

Comment: when you use "exit" on this action, that stop all other action then it's not a good idea to do that. why do you want to do a redirection here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) and [`new_to_publish`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/old_status_to_new_status/) is enough, with some checks, to update post metadata. And you don't need the redirection.

```
<?php
/**
 * Update Postmeta.
 *
 * @param integer $post_id Post ID.
 */
function wpse355298_job_publish_status( $post_id ) {
    // Check autosave.
    if ( wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check post revision.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check permissions.
    if ( 'post' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    }

    $job_published_date = get_the_time( 'Y-m-d', $post_id );
    $expire_date        = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $job_published_date. ' + 60 days' ) );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_job_expires', $expire_date );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse355298_job_publish_status' );
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'wpse355298_job_publish_status' );
```